# Adding section headings to survey in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, survey

I have added a survey web part to my site and would like to add section headings. Is there a way to do this by editing HTML or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add headings by adding a script editor web part to the page and using the jQuery append() method to add the headings to the DOM.